# Getting basic setup of jquery infinite scroll plugin to work in a Tumblr Theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I'm having some trouble getting the jQuery Infinite Scroll plugin by Paul Irish working in my Tumblr theme. Everyone seems to be saying how simple it is so I must be completely stupid as I've been stuck on this one all day.

The following is what I'm using and here is a link to the theme to inspect if anyone can see where I'm going wrong I would really appreciate the help.

Link - http://minori-theme.tumblr.com

At the moment I have the blog set to display 1 post per page and and there are 5 tests posts in total. My basic pagination which works is toggled off when you toggle on the infinite scroll. Which is the current state of the blog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#content').infinitescroll({
        behavior: 'local',
        binder: $('#content'),
        navSelector: ".pagination",
        nextSelector: ".pagination a#next",
        itemSelector: "#content .entry"
    });
  });  

});
</script>
```

Comment: You answered your own question. When infinite scroll is toggled on, you have no `.pagination a#next` in the DOM. Infinitescroll needs this for `nextSelector`. :D

Comment: I see so I shouldn't be toggling this off when I toggle on the infinite scroll? Should I just use CSS to hide the pagination buttons then?

Comment: IIRC, `infinitescroll` will hide the element `navSelector` automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion, I've tried removing the {block:If} like you suggested but still can't seem to get this working. The next/prev buttons just paginate like normal. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my script.